# Is everyone capable of singing?

Tags: voice

So here is the exciting analogy I am going to cite: "While singing, our body is like a musical instrument, having distinct body parts playing different roles in creating the sound we produce." Felicia Ricci (youtube artist)

So, if our body really comes equipped ready to sing, why isn't everybody good at singing when they try? Is it just due to lack of practice or knowledge? Is it true that everybody can sing?

Comment: I'd hardly take a "youtube artist" as being an expert in anything.  Your premise that our physiology is designed (in any evolutionary sense) for carrying a tune is unfounded.

Comment: @Carl would you agree with this post 
Which tells genetics might be behind it counting for differences in quality of sound one can produce. So theoretically everbody is capable of singing but with limitations or differences
http://www.medicaldaily.com/singing-tips-have-certain-skull-shape-and-other-science-behind-carrying-tune-308372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, difficult to answer that questions. Personally, I would say that it is the case. We all have the needed tools and prerequisites to sing properly.
Of course there maybe some diseases or malfunctions which prevent you from singing, but then you would have other concerns than singing =)

I would say, even a person which lacks everything needed for singing, may it be rhythm, finding the right pitch and be able to hold it, even when he isn't capable of doing all that, with enough training and the right instructor everyone can become a good singer. But everyone will need a different amount of time to master his voice.

And I really agree with the statement that when singing, our body is an instrument, the faster one really understands that, the faster he will learn. 
As for the question why not everyone is good at singing: Not everyone tries or wants to be a good singer.

That is my quite generic answer to that question. I am sure someone can give more examples and explain why that is the case and which physiological requirements there are.

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of some physiological defect (which may also preclude the ability to talk) everyone can "sing".  However not everyone will sound the same when they sing, nor will everyone have the same vocal range.  In other words, there is a wide disparity in capability.

Every person is born with different physiology which has a bearing on what they are capable of doing with their bodies.  Not everyone is equipped to be able to run a mile in under four minutes no matter how much they train.  Not everyone can hit a baseball 400 feet or throw a baseball 100 miles per hour.  The same limitations apply to many aspects of singing.

For example some singers have an unusually wide range in terms of the notes they can accurately sing.  While most people are able to increase their range through training and practice, they are usually only able to add a few more notes to either end of their range.  A very small number of people are able to sing notes covering a four octave or more span, before they even start training to expand their range.  The average person will never be able to achieve even a two octave range.

**I should point out that not everyone can "carry a tune" so to speak.**  I know some people who are tone deaf.  No matter how hard they try, they cannot stay in key when they sing.  According to Wikipedia: [Wikipedia Article on Tone Deafness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_deafness)

> Tone deafness is the lack of relative pitch, or the inability to distinguish between musical notes that is not due to the lack of musical training or education.

Also - the quality of a persons voice in terms of how others perceive it, varys from person to person.  While everyone can improve their singing with training and practice, some people just naturally have a more resonant or pleasant sounding singing voice.  The way a person sounds when they sing is influenced by things such as the shape of their throat, the length and thickness of their vocal chords, the shape of their mouth, the shape and size of their nasal cavity, and other aspects of the physical characteristics of their vocal tract and resonators.

Having said all of that, I believe that **with proper training and intentional practice - most people can dramatically improve their singing ability** - including their range, tone and quality of their singing!  A good vocal coach or voice teacher can evaluate a singer's strengths and weaknesses and prescribe specific practice drills and regimens to help them develop and improve their singing voice.

There will always be some physical limitations to how much anyone can improve.  But singing is a way that everyone can express themselves in an enjoyable way that provides personal satisfaction to the singer.  Even if those within earshot don't share in that joy.  I think everyone should be encouraged to sing more often.  It's good for the soul!

Comment: Yes, I think being totally "unable to sing" is quite rare. You might equate it with dyslexia - lots of people have it to a slight extent but most are able to work around it to a degree with hard work.

Comment: @Rockin This question was targetted to my personal pursuit. I wanted to take a decision whether its worth giving time practicing singing.And hey,  Acually i got the answer that exluding the possiblility of illness of any kind I have a high chance that i can try and find out this answer for myself.

Comment: @SanjeevChauhan Absolutely!  Go for it.  The most important thing is for you to have fun and enjoy the process of singing and learning to sing better.  You may discover that other's really enjoy hearing you sing as well.  I did not discover that I could sing well until after the age of 40.  Now I perform professionally and people pay me to sing.  But mostly I do it for the enjoyment of it.

Answer (score 0):

So much of the problem in getting people to sing is not with there ability but getting people confident enough to sing in front of people There seems to be a big mental block with people for some reason that most of the time has very little to do with there actual voice.

It does seem like you need a certain amount of confidence in yourself to be able to sing and that many times problems with singing have some sort of psychology behind them.

Comment: Confidence is good!  But attainment is also good.  Particularly for those listening.

Answer (score -1):

Not everybody can sing.
Not many people can sing well…
… but most people can carry a tune.

I tend to think of it along the lines of the bell-curve model - I've tried to avoid one that gets too specific, as most times you find this it's talking about IQ, so the numbers don't really work for our purposes, but the IQ system is designed to always make 100 the *average* whatever population you measure, be it human beings or marmosets...

[image]

So, what it tries to explain, in extremely broad terms, is that 'most people are average', with far fewer at each extreme.

This type of ability chart tends to work reasonably well for any skill - be it singing, cooking or juggling - because even though the average skill level for the population as a whole is very low for juggling, the average is *still in the middle.*

Unlike IQ [which is where the comparison fails & why I didn't put too much emphasis on it] cooking, juggling & singing can all be improved by practice.

Comment: This is pure speculation.

Comment: I give up. Whatever. Provide a factual answer, with references & I'll retract mine.